# Solving ODE mass balance (numerical method)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From a mass balance in cylindrical coordinate/plug flow reactor of a specie i :

(1/A).∂Fi/∂z= D.[(1/r).∂Ci/∂r+∂2Ci/∂r2] + den.Ri

BC: z=0, Ci=Cio ; r=0, ∂Ci/∂r=0 ; r=r1, ∂Ci/∂r=0

A - cross sectional area of reactor (m2),
F - molar flow rate (mol/s),
C - concentration (mol/m3),
D - Diffusivity,
den - catalyst bed density,
R - Rate equation (=k.Ci or k.Ci.Cj... depends on specie)

Could you pls advice how to solve it with numerical method?
(I heard a finite element or runge-kutta method but can not understand how to develop a step to particularly solving this equation in a computer.)

Thank you,

Nattaporn

Comment: Some of the other users have voted to migrate to Math.StackExchange. Personally I think there's a possibility that a more suitable website is [Computational Science](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

Discretize along z using Euler's method (constant step size along z), and a simple RK45 along r. This will yield a system of coupled ODEs. Check out CVODES documentation for a similar example.